# Better way to iterate over a list?

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

I am using `fitz` to scrape PDFs. I use the following code to generate a list of words located in the pdf.

```
import fitz
doc = fitz.open("very_important_document.pdf")

for page in doc.pages(0, 1, 1): # reads just the first page
    wlist = page.get_text("words")

doc.close()
```

This returns a list of tuples of the following form:

```
(x0, y0, x1, y1, "lines in the block", block_no, block_type)
```

Some text I need to pull out comes after multiple lines, for example:

```
wlist = [(x0, y0, x1, y1, "sample", block_no, block_type),
         (x0, y0, x1, y1, "population", block_no, block_type),
         (x0, y0, x1, y1, "1,451,990", block_no, block_type),
         (x0, y0, x1, y1, "target", block_no, block_type),
         (x0, y0, x1, y1, "population", block_no, block_type)
         (x0, y0, x1, y1, "5,678", block_no, block_type)
```

If I want to pull out sample_population and target_population I can just increase my count by 1 since it always comes on the line after the indicator text:

```
sample_pop = 0
target_pop = 0
for i in range(len(wlist)):
    if (wlist[i][4] == "sample") & (wlist[i+1][4] == "population"):
        sample_pop = wlist[i+2][4]
    if (wlist[i][4] == "target") & (wlist[i+1][4] == "population":
        target_pop = wlist[i+2][4]
```

This code works but I end up getting an `IndexError('list index out of range')` as this checks every item in the list of extracted words. Any cleaner/more pythonic way to parse this list?

Comment: Have you considered iterating over `range(len(wlist) - 2)` to ensure you will always be able to do `[i + 2]`?

Comment: Note that `&` is _bitwise and_, which is not short-circuiting. The boolean short-circuiting and operator is `and`

Comment: Also, your question is unclear. What is the situation you get an `IndexError` in? Did you do any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: if text  "metadata" is not needed maybe use just `page.get_text("text").split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only look ahead if `wlist[i][4] == "sample"` or `"target"`. I use a dictionary to avoid double-checking.

```
pop_dict = {"sample": 0, "target": 0}

for i in range(len(wlist)):
    if wlist[i][4] in ["sample", "target"]:
        if wlist[i + 1][4] == "population":
            pop_dict[wlist[i][4]] = wlist[i + 2][4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an indexing error because your loop goes up to the last (and before last) item and you are systematically referencing i+1 and i+2 (which are beyond the end of the list).

If your data is always organized in groups of 3 items, you could add a step to the loop's range: `range(0,len(wlist),3)`, if not, make it stop earlier `range(len(wlist)-2)`

You could use zip to avoid indexing into `wlist` altogether:

```
for w0,w1,w2 in zip(wlist,wlist[1:],wlist[2:]): # step by 3 if applicable
    k0,k1,k2 = w0[4],w1[4],w2[4]
    if k1 != "population": continue
    if k0 == "sample":
       sample_pop = k2
    elif k0 == "target":
       target_pop = k2
```

*Note that, depending on the data, this loop may assign `sample_pop` or `target_pop` multiple times resulting in only the last value being kept.  This may or may not be your intention. If it is, there may be more efficient ways to obtain that result.*

If the last value is actually what you are looking for, you could use zip to extract all the keys and use a dictionary to manage the key:value pairs:

```
_,_,_,keys,*_ = zip(*wlist)
D = dict( zip(zip(keys,keys[1:]),keys[2:]) ) # step by 3 if applicable
sample_pop = D["sample","population"]
target_pop = D["target","population"]
```